# How to avoid (nested) if/else statements by using BeautifulSoup with a decorator?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

#### Problem description

Because of the fact that BeautifulSoup is returning a `soup object` or `None`, there have to be as much `if else` statements in a function as subsequent searches via `.find` or `.find_all` will occur.

#### Question

How can one avoid this by using a decorator (or a similar approach)?

#### Example

Lets say there are two different html sites (with these example snippets):

```
# example with wanted class in html file
<td class='translation'>
    <span class='italiano'>ciao</span>
    <span class='french'>au revoir</span>
    <span class='polish'>cześć</span>
</td>

# example without wanted class in another html file
<td class='no_translation'>
    foo
</td>
```

If you doing the search below on snippets everything is ok for the first html snippet, but for the second you will get this:

```
>>> soup.find('td', class_='translation').find('span', class_='polish')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

There are two obvious ways to handle this `AttributeError`:

```
# using if-else statements for every result of .find or .findall
def possibility_1():
    translation = soup.find('td', class_='translation')
    if translation:
        polish = translation.find('span', class_='polish')
        return polish
    return None

# use a try-except block for the problem
def possibility_2():
    try:
        translation = soup.find('td', class_='translation')
        polish = translation.find('span', class_='polish')
        return polish
    except AttributeError:
        return None
```

What about a third solution by using a decorator function for that? How can this be done?

```
@decorator_name
def get_desired_result():
    translation = soup.find('td', class_='translation')
    polish = translation.find('span', class_='polish')
    return polish
```

Comment: You mean like [`contextlib.suppress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.suppress)? Where is **your attempt** to implement `decorator_name`, and what is the problem with it?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for the [`contextlib.supress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.suppress), but this works only for python >= 3.4 (using 2.7). But I see, there are also possibilites with [`contextlib.contextmanager`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager). It's little more complicated. There is yet no attempt of implementation for `decorator_name`, because I'm not sure if it's the best idea, at all. Is it more like a matter of taste using decorators or is it a good way for what I want? If yes, I can try to provide an attempt.

Comment: What's the actual problem with using `try` and `except`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I will have many functions like `get_desired_result` and I don't want to write `try` and `except` for each of them. I would like to have a general solution for that with reusable code for all projects. But setting `try` and `except` maybe could be done in a decorator function to fulfill my requirements, right?

Comment: Yes, you could do it with a decorator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the comments (nearly a discussion) made by *@jonrsharpe* and the answer by *[@Logan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32122266/how-to-avoid-nested-if-else-statements-by-using-beautifulsoup-with-a-decorator/32127285#32127285)* I would stick to the decorator idea, but with getting information where the search will return `None`.

Here is my decorator as one possible solution.

```
import sys
import inspect
from functools import wraps
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Decorator with returning None and trace info if
# soup.find or soup.find_all fails at a certain point
def robust_soup(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except AttributeError:
            # just an example without formatting
            print inspect.getinnerframes(sys.exc_info()[2])
    return wrapper
```

now I can use

```
# a good working example
soup_good = BeautifulSoup("""
<td class='translation'>
    <span class='italiano'>ciao</span>
    <span class='french'>au revoir</span>
    <span class='polish'>cześć</span>
</td>""")

# an example which would lead to AttributeError if not handled
soup_bad = BeautifulSoup("""
<td class='no_translation'>
    something uninteresting
</td>""")

@robust_soup
def get_desired_result(soup):
    translation = soup.find('td', class_='translation')
    polish = translation.find('span', class_='polish')
    print polish

>>> # with a soup containing information
>>> get_desired_result(soup_good)
<span class='polish'>cześć</span>

>>> # with a soup which normally fails
>>> get_desired_result(soup_bad)
# some debugging output from inspect module (also
# with information where last error occured!)
None
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a decorator and manually checking for `None` via if/then, you might consider using your own function instead of `.find` and `.find_all`.

Also, there are 2 issues with returning plain-old `None`.

- You have no idea where the error is propagating from, so debugging would be hard.
- After returning `None`, you might end up doing something like `soup.find_all("a")` or `link["href"]` on what is, in actuality, `None`. This wouldn't help you at all.

So you might try something like this:

```
class PseudoNone(object):
    """"
    You can call it.
    You can beat it with a stick.
    It will return PseudoNone!
    And you can trace where the None did come from!!"""
    debug = {}
    def __init__(self, created_at):
        PseudoNone.debug[self] = created_at
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return self
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self
    def __bool__(self):
        return False
```

This '`None`' shouldn't have those issues. Also, each instance is created with some identifier of what caused the `None`. All 'children `None`' caused by `PseudoNone.__call__` or `__getitem__` are really just the same object in memory, and thus have the same initial cause of failure in `PseudoNone.debug[obj]`. Good for debugging!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

xml = """
<td class='translation'>
    <span class='italiano'>ciao</span>
    <span class='french'>au revoir</span>
    <span class='polish'>cześć</span>
</td>"""

def find_all(soup, *args, **kwargs):
    results = soup.find_all(*args, **kwargs)
    if not results:
        return PseudoNone((soup, args, kwargs))
    else:
        return results

def find(soup, *args, **kwargs):
    "As far as I know, BeautifulSoup.find is internally just BeautifulSoup.find_all(*args)[0]"
    results = find_all(soup, *args, **kwargs)
    return results[0]

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml)

translation = find(soup, 'td', class_='translation')

erroneous_translation = find(soup, 'td', class_='BADTRANSLATIONS')
```

...

```
print translation
    <td class="translation">
    <span class="italiano">ciao</span>
    <span class="french">au revoir</span>
    <span class="polish">czeĹÄ</span>
    </td>

print erroneous_translation
    <__main__.PseudoNone object at 0x7fd4bcc18790>

print erroneous_translation("foo")
    <__main__.PseudoNone object at 0x7fd4bcc18790>

print erroneous_translation["baz"]
    <__main__.PseudoNone object at 0x7fd4bcc18790>

print find_all(erroneous_translation, "something")
    <__main__.PseudoNone object at 0x7fd4bcc18790>
```

Omg, this is a PseudoNone! That's not what I wanted. Where did I go wrong!!?

```
print PseudoNone.debug[erroneous_translation]
    (<html><body><td class="translation">
    <span class="italiano">ciao</span>
    <span class="french">au revoir</span>
    <span class="polish">czeĹÄ</span>
    </td></body></html>, ('td',), {'class_': 'BADTRANSLATIONS'})
```

Notes:

- Use `isinstance(qux, PseudoNone)`, not `==None`. (We can't subclass`NoneType`)
- If `PseudoNone.debug` gets too large for memory, consider hashing the `*args` and `**kwargs` in the values of PseudoNone.debug (and/or making use of `@functools.lru_cache` in python3)
- This might be a hack.